# Can I make a React component re-render itself when it's attribute is a reactive data source from Meteor?

Tags: meteor, reactjs

e.g. I have a user profile name component:

```
Name = React.createClass({
  render() {
    let name = this.props.user ? this.props.user.profile.name : '';
    return <span>{name}</span>;
  }
})
```

How can I get the following name tag update itself automatically when user signs in/signs out:

```
<Name user={Meteor.user()} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this is to use the React mixin, `ReactMeteorData`. In `getMeteorData`, make Meteor user's identity a reactive data source.

```
Name = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
    getMeteorData() {
        return {
            user: Meteor.user()
        };
    },
    render() {
        return <div>{ this.data.user ? this.data.user.username : '' }</div>;
    }
});
```

If the user identity is meant to be passed via React properties, move the reactive data source to the containing component.

```
Name = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <div>{ this.props.user ? this.props.user.username : '' }</div>;
    }
});

Parent= React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
    getMeteorData() {
        return {
            user: Meteor.user() // Or any reactive data here
        };
    },
    render() {
        return <Name user={ this.data.user } />;
    }
});
```

Component's `render` function is not reactive according to the [documentation](http://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/meteor-data/#warning-render-is-not-reactive). `ReactMeteorData` mixin is the easiest addition to achieve reactivity.

> If you access a Meteor reactive data source from your component's
>   render method, the component will not automatically rerender when data
>   changes. If you want your component to rerender with the most
>   up-to-date data, access all reactive functions from inside the
>   getMeteorData method.

Comment: Thanks @Season. But what I really want is to pass any user to the user attribute, not just the current user e.g. <name user={post.user()} /> . If the user instance is reactive (e.g. Meteor.user()) then, the component should be re-rendered when Meteor.user() changes. Is that possible?

Comment: @Chih-Chao Lam, Sounds like it becomes the responsibility of the parent component to decide what the `user` property would be. Moving the reactive data source to the parent component would make it.

Comment: Thanks @Season, was hoping to avoid that, but can't think of simpler way either. In this case <Parent> is not really a parent of <Name /> in the React owner sense but really a wrapper to ensure reactivity for Meteor.user(), right?

Comment: @Chih-Chao Lam, Yes, that is what it's supposed to be. From the documentation, I cannot think of an easy way to avoid it either.

Answer (score 0):

My component wasn't rerendering (because it wasn't wrapped around a reactive data source but needed to show different things depending on Meteor.user.

This is kind of a hacky anti-pattern and not for everyone, but I used the  `componentWillUpdate()` function like below. The 'problem' here is that you're supposed to depend on reactive data to create rerenders, but (for reasons too long to explain) I couldn't do that in my case, so had to resort to this method. The `if` statements are in place to prevent the code from infinitely rerendering itself. It's not ideal, but it worked for me

`componentWillUpdate() {
    if(Meteor.userId() && !this.state.loggedIn ) {
       this.setState({loggedIn: true});
       ... (render code is based off of the state of this.state.loggedIn
    }
    if (!Meteor.userId() && this.state.loggedIn)) {
       this.setState({loggedIn: false});
    }
  }`